# race condition with angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that has 2 attributes:
1. a title object passed from the controller. 
2. a onchange function passed from the controller.

```js
scope: {
  title: '=',
  change: '&'
}


//on the link function I update the object, and call the function.

link: function(scope) {
    scope.setValue = function() {
      scope.title = "Yaniv"
      scope.change();
    };
},
```

somehow, eventhough I wrote it the opposite way, it seems that first it calls the function, and only then it updates the title object.
What is the best way to overcome this? I already thought about using setTimeout, and it actually worked this thing around. but, I wonder why this issue happened, and whether there is a cleaner solution here.
attached JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sz82r7pg/

Answer (score 1):

`title` two-way binding is updated in parent scope *at the end* of the digest. Until then `title` value change is not propagated from directive scope to parent scope.

`setValue` is called by `ng-click` and runs *during* the digest. This means that `change` should be called after the current digest, with `setTimeout` or `$imeout`:

```
   scope.setValue = function () {
                scope.title = "Yaniv"
                $imeout(() => scope.change());
   };
```

Which indicates bad smell and XY problem, because `title` update is already tied to digest, and `change` is redundant. It's the job for the framework. `title` changes should be tracked with

```
$scope.$watch('title', (newValue, oldValue) => {
  if (newValue === oldValue) return;
  ...
});
```

in parent scope.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I didnt want to use $watch that's why I came up with the change function, and got to that issue.

Comment: @Yaniv If you have `change: '&'`, new value can be passed with `scope.change(val)`, ` title: '='` is redundant, and vice versa. Basically, it is either one or another. Is there a reason behind your decision? Because `$scope.$watch` is idiomatic, *cleaner solution*.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that the directive has its own [isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) object, of which the title attribute is bound to the title of the controller scope. This databinding is basically done by watches, and you might know that change detection using watches is not instantaneous, happens inside a digest loop, which always happens after the change was made, and the call stack is emtpied (in the next micro/macro task. I don't know exactly which, but doesn't matter here). Calling a function is however instantaneous. So what happens is the following:

- Set title of directive scope
- Call change, which calls foo, the controller scope title is the old one
- After the call angular runs a digest loop, notices the change in the directive scope, and propagates it to the controller scope

This is totally expected behaviour. The easiest way in your case is not to use your own change detection, but use the one built into angular:

```js
angular.module('zippyModule', [])
.controller("Ctrl3", function ($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Ori';
  $scope.$watch("title", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      alert(newValue);
    }
  });
})
.directive('zippy', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      title:'=zTitle'
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="setValue()">What would be the value of title??</button>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.setValue = function () {
        scope.title = "Yaniv";
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  font-size:24px;
  margin:40px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="zippyModule">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
    <div zippy z-title="title"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While writing this snippet I realized you are using an ancient version of angularjs in the fiddle (1.0.2). I had to make a little modification to work with 1.5.x.

If you dont want to use watches, then the best you can do is to justt pass the new title to the change function.

```js
angular.module('zippyModule', [])
.controller("Ctrl3", function ($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Ori';
  $scope.foo = function(newTitle) {
    alert(newTitle);
  };
})
.directive('zippy', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      change: '&'
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="setValue()">What would be the value of title??</button>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.setValue = function () {
        scope.change({title:"Yaniv"});
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  font-size:24px;
  margin:40px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="zippyModule">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
    <div zippy change="foo(title)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

It turned out in the comments you wish to make a somewhat tighter coupling between the controller and the directive. Such a thing is usually considered a bad design, but there are times when this is the only right solution (most of the time when non-angular components are involved). So the idea is to create an API object, which can directly be manipulated, and pass it to the directive.

```js
angular.module('zippyModule', [])
.controller("Ctrl3", function ($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Ori';
  $scope.fooApiImpl = {
    title: "Ori",
    change: function() {
      alert($scope.fooApiImpl.title);
    }
  };
})
.directive('zippy', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      fooApi: '='
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="setValue()">What would be the value of title??</button>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.setValue = function () {
        scope.fooApi.title = "Yaniv";
        scope.fooApi.change();
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  font-size:24px;
  margin:40px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="zippyModule">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl3">
    <div zippy foo-api="fooApiImpl"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tamas for you kind response. Using the $watch on the controller is what I did in the first place but it looked not so elegant code to me. so I thought calling a change function would be a bette yet maintainable solution. the other way is just a workaround as I wanted to change the original title object in the parent controller, and not sending it as a parameter. Thanks.

Comment: @Yaniv There are ways to do that, but its a sign of bad design decisions. See my update (coming in a minute)

Comment: I will pass the new value as a parameter to the change function and remove the scope.title change in the directive. that way i wont need to rely on the digest loop to finish. the change function will assign the new value to the title.

Comment: Great, so you go with the second version. Hope it'll work well for you.